# Multiple for loops issues

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I have two arrays keys and subGrps.
Using these two creating new array with mapping keys to subGrps array.

```js
var keys = ["Subgroup", "0-3", "3-10", "11-40"];
var subGrps = ["SP_20k", "SP_40k", "SP_60k"];

var arrayOfObjects = [];

subGrps.forEach(function(id) {
  keys.forEach(function(item) {
    if (item === "Subgroup") {
      arrayOfObjects.push({
        [item]: id
      });
    } else {
      arrayOfObjects.push({
        [item]: ""
      });
    }
  });
});

console.log(arrayOfObjects);
```

Expected Output:

```
  [{
    "Subgroup" : "SP_20k",
    "0-3": "",
    "3-10": "",
    "11-40": ""
  },
  {
    "Subgroup" : "SP_40k",
    "0-3": "",
    "3-10": "",
    "11-40": ""
  },
  {
    "Subgroup" : "SP_60k",
    "0-3": "",
    "3-10": "",
    "11-40": ""
  }]
```

`forEach` is good option ?  for grouping objects of `keys array` and `subGrps array` to get that output.
  What am i missing to get Expected Output ?
  can someone plz help me?

Comment: is your expected output correctly written. please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to iterate over your `subGrps` array, creating an object with the `Subgroup` key set to the value from `subGrps` and using [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) to add empty values for the other entries in the `keys` array:

```js
var keys = ["Subgroup", "0-3", "3-10", "11-40"];
var subGrps = ["SP_20k", "SP_40k", "SP_60k"];

var arrayOfObjects = subGrps.map(v => Object.assign({
    "Subgroup": v
  },
  ...keys.slice(1).map(k => ({
    [k]: ""
  }))
));

console.log(arrayOfObjects);
```

This could potentially be simplified to:

```js
var keys = ["Subgroup", "0-3", "3-10", "11-40"];
var subGrps = ["SP_20k", "SP_40k", "SP_60k"];

var arrayOfObjects = subGrps.map(v => Object.assign({},
  ...keys.map(k => ({
    [k]: k == 'Subgroup' ? v : ""
  }))
));

console.log(arrayOfObjects);
```

Answer (score 1):

**You can create the object at first and add the keys in a loop.**

```js
var keys = ["Subgroup", "0-3", "3-10", "11-40"];
var subGrps = ["SP_20k", "SP_40k", "SP_60k"];

// creates the object with keys once
// you can also use foreach to create this keysObj too.
var keysObj = keys.reduce((resObj, acc) => {
  resObj[acc] = ''
  return resObj
}, {})

// uses keysObj to generate array of objects
var arrayOfObjects = subGrps.map(subGrp => ({...keysObj, Subgroup: subGrp}))
console.log(arrayOfObjects)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
const arr = [];

subGrps.forEach(subGrp => {
   const obj = {}
   keys.forEach(key => obj[key] = (key === 'Subgroup') ? subGrp : '' );
   arr.push(obj);
})

console.log(arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why `"Subgroup"` is mixed in with the other keys if you want to treat it specially, but here you go:

```js
const [sgKey, ...keys] = ["Subgroup", "0-3", "3-10", "11-40"];
const subGrps = ["SP_20k", "SP_40k", "SP_60k"];

const result = subGrps.map(sg => {
  const obj = {
    [sgKey]: sg
  }
  for (const k of keys) {
    obj[k] = ''
  }
  return obj
});

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this:

```js
var keys = ["Subgroup", "0-3", "3-10", "11-40"];
var subGrps = ["SP_20k", "SP_40k", "SP_60k"];

var arrayOfObjects = [];

subGrps.forEach(function(id) {
  var obj = {}
  keys.forEach(function(item) {
    if (item === "Subgroup") {
      obj[item]= id
      arrayOfObjects.push(obj);
    } else {
      obj[item] = ""
      arrayOfObjects.push(obj);
    }
  });
});

console.log(arrayOfObjects);
```

Answer (score 0):

I modified your code a little as below:

```
var keys = ["Subgroup", "0-3", "3-10", "11-40"];
var subGrps = ["SP_20k", "SP_40k", "SP_60k"];

var arrayOfObjects = [];

subGrps.forEach(function(id) {
  var obj = {};
  arrayOfObjects.push(obj);
  keys.forEach(function(item) {
    if (item === "Subgroup") {
      obj[item] = id;
    } else {
      obj[item] = "";
    }
  });
});

console.log(arrayOfObjects);
```